# Can someone explain how this ruby basic-calculator code handles addition and subtraction?

Tags: ruby, math

So I was working on a Codewars problem [here](http://www.codewars.com/kata/calculator/ruby), and found some code posted to Github that works out-of-the-box. Problem is, I don't understand how part of it works. Here are the Codewars directions:

> Description:
>
> Create a simple calculator that given a string of operators (+ - * and /) and numbers separated by spaces returns the value of that expression
>
> Example:
>
> Calculator.new.evaluate("2 / 2 + 3 * 4 - 6") # => 7
>
> Remember about the order of operations! Multiplications and divisions have a higher priority and should be performed left-to-right. Additions and subtractions have a lower priority and should also be performed left-to-right.

Here's the code:

```
class Calculator
    def evaluate(string)
        operator_stack = []
        number_stack = []
        string.split(" ").each do |token|
            if /\d/.match(token) 
                number_stack << token.to_i
            elsif operator_stack.length > 0 && /[*]|[\/]/.match(operator_stack[-1])
                    x, y = number_stack.pop, number_stack.pop
                    temp_result = y.send(operator_stack.pop, x)
                    number_stack << temp_result
                    operator_stack << token
            else
                  operator_stack << token
            end
        end

   while(number_stack.length > 0 && operator_stack.length > 0)
    x, y = number_stack.shift, number_stack.shift
    temp_result = x.send(operator_stack.shift,y)
    number_stack.unshift(temp_result)
   end
   return number_stack[0]
    end
end
```

Now I've learned enough Ruby that I can read through and understand what the various functions do, but when it comes to the mathematical operations the code does, I don't see where or how it handles addition and subtraction. There is some regex that's used to match for multiplication and division present in this line:

```
elsif operator_stack.length > 0 && /[*]|[\/]/.match(operator_stack[-1])
```

But since I don't see the plus or minus sign anywhere in the code, I don't get how it performs those operations. Can anyone help?

BTW, I'm done with the Codewars problem and have moved on. I also discovered you can solve this calculator problem with "instance_eval string", which blew my mind when I first saw it. But, it makes sense after reading through [what I found here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval). I should have guessed that there was a one-liner that would work as a basic calculator :)

I would still like to know how this code handles addition and subtraction. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4):

The actual operations are performed in these lines:

```
temp_result = y.send(operator_stack.pop, x)
```

and later

```
temp_result = x.send(operator_stack.shift,y)
```

which says "send the `operator_stack.shift/pop` message with parameter `y` to object`x`, which is basically the same as doing `x <operator> y` where `<operator>` is the operator on top of `operator_stack`